# how to rerender a component when hash change and change the state

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to monitor hash change and then change the state and rerender the component. so I want to know where to monitor the hash change in component lifecycle

example:

```
#/detail/:id  =>  #/detail

{info:[a:1,b:2]} => {info:[]}
```

.#/detail/:id and #/detail are the same components

Answer (score 21):

If you want your component to have event listeners, you want to add those event listeners in componentDidMount, and remove the event listeners in componentWillUmount.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", this.doSomething, false);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("hashchange", this.doSomething, false);
}
```

Comment: I know this way, but the #/detail and #/detial/:id is the same component.so the method componentDidMount only once, When I visited #/detail:id it was finished. so when I visit the #/detail is not working。

Comment: I would recommend you look at https://github.com/reactjs/react-router, but if you're trying to roll your own, you should have a parent component created as I described. It's also difficult to offer a more robust answer based on your post. Not sure what you mean with the :id. if you're trying to create your own custom hash based routing, again, I recommend react-router.

Comment: sorry, my english is not good. I'm using react-router. Thank you

Comment: When i used the `componentDidMount` it fires twice, one for the previous url state and another for the new url state with the new hash,

Answer (score 3):

Use `HashRouter` in index.js and `withRouter` to get path parameters and `getDerivedStateFromProps` to handle the states based on the url's hash.

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <App />
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {

  state = { productId: null };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps){
    const { location: { pathname } } = nextProps;       // pathname e.g.: '/detail/:8'
    const productId = pathname.split(':')[1] || null;   // ProductId: 8 OR null;
    return { productId };
  }

  ...

}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Answer (score 3):

For **React newer version**

Use `window.location.hash` with `useEffect`

```js
useEffect( ()=> {
        doSomething();
  }, [window.location.hash])
```

Comment: React does not detect changes to hash by default, the component will not rerender if only the hash is changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor the change in route params you may do that it the lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps`

#### componentWillReceiveProps

> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before
>   render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The
>   old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState()
>   within this function will not trigger an additional render.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
  const {params: {id}} = nextProps;
  if(id !== this.props.params.id){
    /////////
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it in react. I used this to detect hash change and scroll to specific element depending on hash value.

Comment: Doesn't this assume you're using ReactRouter (or something similar) though?